# SQL Server 2012 - Setting an Identity column on a Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

I am trying to set a primary key column to Identity = Yes, on the database diagram.

I clicked on the column to set, and then pressed F4 to bring the Properties for that column. I usually scroll to Identity and change that to Yes but it is not letting me do that now. I think this is happening because the column is set as a foreign key in other tables?

I do not want to remove the joins, is there anyway I can do that?

Here is some screenshots:

The key to change:

[image]

The F4 (Properties); change is disabled:

[image]

Comment: You cannot change an existing column to be an `IDENTITY` - you have to create a **new column** and set it to be `IDENTITY`

Comment: @marc_s - SSMS would usually allow you to and generate the script to rebuild the table. The reason it is greyed out here is you can't make a `uniqueidentifier` column an `identity` column. Identity requires an `int` or `numeric(x,0)` datatype.

Comment: @marc_s - In reality it copies the whole table to a new one then drops the original and renames the copy.

Comment: did my answer solve your problem ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I have actually defaulted to deleting the key and recreating it as an int instead of the UniqueIdentifier. I appreciate your answering and I know it could be a good solution for those who don't have the 'luxury of recreating the column as I did in my newly designed database.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a table test:

```
create table test(id int, a int)

insert test values(3,1)
alter table test add id_new int identity(1,1)

go

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test ON
delete from test
output deleted.id, deleted.a, deleted.id into test(id, a, id_new)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test OFF

go

alter table test drop column id

EXEC sp_rename 
@objname= 'test.id_new', 
@newname = 'id', 
@objtype = 'COLUMN'

declare @maxid int = (select max(id) from test)
DBCC CHECKIDENT(test, RESEED, @maxid);
```

Your column ID be an identity column

You can test here that everything works:

```
insert test values(10)
select * from test
```